# PHP substr() dos not work

Tags: php

How is this possible?

```
echo strlen($in);                      //216 OK
echo strlen(substr( $in, 74, 129 ));   //129 WRONG
```

The 2º line should be 55 not 129.

Comment: The third argument of [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) is called `$length`, so what do you imagine it do to?

Comment: [The fact that your code doesn't work doesn't imply a problem with substr](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about failing to read the PHP documentation

Answer (score 5):

The third argument to [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is a **length**, so you're taking a length of 129 bytes from offset 74 of $in, so your result will be 129 bytes long